# Automatically kill/timeout long running requests on Flask, uWSGI, and NGINX

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask app running behind uWSGI and NGINX that occasionally sees very long running requests. Of course, the ideal solution whenever these happen is to fix whatever's causing those requests to run so long. I'm working on that, but also want to have the app or server themselves capable of killing requests that run for too long as a catchall in case long running requests do get through somehow, so they don't slow everything else down. I've tried modifying some of the uWSGI timeout settings, but these don't help the problem and I still see very long running requests in New Relic:

```
uwsgi_connect_timeout = 2
uwsgi_send_timeout = 2
uwsgi_read_timeout = 2
```

I've seen some stuff about having uWSGI workers get killed and reload when this happens, but I'd really rather just have the request get killed without needing to restart the worker.

At this point I'm not even sure where the appropriate place to look for this kind of thing would be. I'm guessing it's in uWSGI or Flask, but figured I'd mention NGINX as well, just in case.

Comment: Are you sure the timeouts are applied ? I would double-check that your running nginx actually is running with the right config: `nginx -V` should help. You might also want to tweak some of nginx's timeouts `proxy_connect_timeout` `proxy_send_timeout` or `proxy_read_timeout`.

Comment: @ddr2 those timeouts are on uWSGI, not NGINX. I figured this is something that should be set on the uWSGI side, so it just returns a 504 to NGINX. The most important part is that uWSGI should stop devoting CPU to the task.